# How to stop foreach at certain point so undefined error isn't thrown

Tags: php, html, arrays, loops, associative-array

At the moment I have an Array like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
[username] => Humza 
[Reputation] => -50 
[Question_Title] => Will 
[Question] => Yes Ofc 
[Rating] => 101 
[Category] => Programming
[num_answers] => 0 ) 

[1] => Array ( 
[username] => Humza 
[Reputation] => -50 
[Question_Title] => This will not have an answer 
[Question] => This does not derserve an Answer 
[Rating] => -100
[Category] => Programming 
[num_answers] => 2 ) 

[2] => Array ( 
[AnswerUserName] => Humza 
[Answer] => Yup? 
[Answer_Rating] => 909 
[Reputation] => -50 )

[3] => Array ( 
[AnswerUserName] => God 
[Answer] => Wohoo 
[Answer_Rating] => 15
[Reputation] => 9999 ) )
```

I am using a foreach loop to display it:

```
foreach($Quest as $Value)
{
  echo '<font size="3">',"<b>Username: </b>", $Value['username'],"&nbsp;","&nbsp;",
  "<b>User Reputation: </b>",$Value['Reputation'],"&nbsp;","&nbsp;",
  "<b>Question Rating:</b>",$Value['Rating'],"&nbsp;","&nbsp;",'</font>',
  "<b>Category: </b>",$Value['Category'],"&nbsp;","&nbsp;",
  "<b>Number Of Answers Available:  </b>",$Value['num_answers'];
}
```

Eventually this will start printing out 'Error: Undefined Index' I know why it happens but I would like to know how to stop this, so that I can start displaying the answer part of the array.

Any help is really appreciated
Thanks, in Advance.

Comment: exit or break, i do not remember :)

Comment: Really it's that easy? o_o

Comment: to exit from a loop? yes ^_^

Comment: Yep, it's as simple as that: It's surprisingly common to need to break out of any loop early.

Comment: @4444 example for validating or checking ^_^

Comment: Hmm I learned something new today XD

Comment: Welcome to computer science, there's always something new to learn!

Comment: Does isset() work with mouseover? When I tried to incorporate it with mouseover it wouldn't display anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of stopping your loop at a particular point, why not `echo` based on the sub-array values' existence?

```
foreach($Quest as $Value)
{
  echo '<font size="3">'; // No one uses <font> anymore by the way
  if (isset($Value['username'])) echo "<b>Username: </b>", $Value['username'],"&nbsp;","&nbsp;";
  if (isset($Value['Reputation'])) echo "<b>User Reputation: </b>",$Value['Reputation'],"&nbsp;","&nbsp;";
  if (isset($Value['Rating'])) echo "<b>Question Rating:</b>",$Value['Rating'],"&nbsp;","&nbsp;",'</font>';
  if (isset($Value['Category'])) echo "<b>Category: </b>",$Value['Category'],"&nbsp;","&nbsp;";
  if (isset($Value['num_answers'])) echo "<b>Number Of Answers Available:  </b>",$Value['num_answers'];
}
```

Comment: This didn't occur to me, this is why I love this site.

Comment: @MarcoMura While you were correct and I missed the `</font>` within the echoes, your edit was an attempt to comment on my answer. You should have left a comment and I would've corrected accordingly, or suggested an edit removing the `echo '</font>';` with your commentary in the edit reason. Thanks for the catch though!

Comment: i did not remove that because i was unsure of what you wanted to do. Next time i will only post a comment =)

Comment: @MarcoMura An edit removing the echo would have been fine. You were right and I would have accepted the edit on that logic :)

Comment: A suggestion will be not use &nbsp; but use css to distantiate elements :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with mouseover, it will mouse over but nothing will show so I assume you can't use isset with mouseover? Can you confirm?

Comment: @ShatteredPheonix Mouseover (I'm assuming in Javascript) has absolutely nothing to do with PHP. Open a new question since it's out of the scope of your original problem.